# Generating WPA/WPA2 Key in linux bash?

Tags: wireless, security, wpa2, wpa

How can I generate a new random wpa/wap2 key in the linux terminal? I tried pwgen but this is not generating hexadecimal values.

Comment: For WPA(2) I would use all regular characters to generate from rather than just hexadecimal ones. What is your reason to generate a password from such a selected set?

Comment: @gertvdijk this is required by the router

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For instance, if you want a password with the maximum character length, i.e. 63, you can enter either of the following 2 commands:

1. `makepasswd --chars=63`
2. `openssl rand -base64 63`

**UPDATE:**

Here is a better command I've found for this purpose since I first wrote this answer:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=48 count=1 status=none | base64 | tr +/ -_
```

Actually I use this zenity-powered script to generate such a password from time to time:

```
#!/bin/bash
RNDPWD="$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=48 count=1 status=none | base64 | tr +/ -_)"
echo $RNDPWD | tr -d '\n' | xclip -i -selection clipboard
zenity --question --title="Random Password" --text="<i>Password Copied to Clipboard:</i>\n\n$RNDPWD\n\n<b>Would you like to generate another one?</b>" --width=500 --height=150
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
    "~/.bin/Password-Generator-GUI"
fi
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need to generate a 64 characters long, hexadecimal password, which is required by my router.

Comment: then you need `openssl rand -hex 32`

Comment: @Sadi: "openssl rand -base64 63" generated 63 bytes of information, 84 base64 characters.

Comment: @beroal thanks for the feedback. I don't know what happened in nearly 4 years, but I've added another command - even a script - now which I hope will serve this purpose much reliably and much better ( and much longer ;-)

Comment: Thanks. And why do you run "tr +/ -_"?

Comment: @beroal its purpose is to replace any "+" and "/" characters (which, I don't remember now, might create problems in some cases) with "-" and "_" respectively.

Comment: @danny Maybe you can accept this as **the answer** now - so that this good website doesn't show some many unanswered questions - although many of them are actually answered ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To generate the best possible password (with the highest entropy possible), one should use all of the ASCII printable characters - from 32 (space) to 126 (tilde, ~). This can be archieved with (for an example maximum password length of 63 characters):

```
< /dev/urandom tr -cd "[:print:]" | head -c 63; echo
```

To not include the space one can use `[:graph:]` character set and there are also others described in the `tr`'s manpage.